# Difference between P1_item1 and P1_Item2 in form Apex Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have P1_item1 and P1_Item2 in the form of filling, Can I create a diem stock, so if the difference between them is greater than + - 0.0001 then I could write a table.Something like this

```
Declare 
Begin 
If (:P1_item1 - :P1_item2) > +- 0.0001 then 
INSERT INTO eror_table
 VALUES ('1', sysdate, 'P1_SEALING_OBJECT);

  end if;

end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ABS()` function which gives the absolute value.

Try this:

```
Declare 
Begin 
  If abs(:P1_item1 - :P1_item2) > 0.0001 then 
    INSERT INTO eror_table
    VALUES ('1', sysdate, 'P1_SEALING_OBJECT');
 end if;
end;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you very much) You helped me a lot, Could you look at one more question ??? They are almost identical) But the question is more precise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902052/exceeding-the-permissible-coordinate-zone?noredirect=1#comment102225272_57902052

Answer (score 0):

```
   DECLARE
    v_value number;
    BEGIN 
    v_value  = abs(:P1_item1 - :P1_item2);
      IF  v_value > 0.0001 then 
        INSERT INTO eror_table
        VALUES ('1', sysdate, 'P1_SEALING_OBJECT');
     END IF;
    END;
```

You can use abs() function which gives the absolute value.